# Error creating bean with name 'com.example.demo.RepositoryTest.UtentiRepositoryTest'

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I got this error running the test class UtentiRepositoryTest.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'com.example.demo.RepositoryTest.UtentiRepositoryTest': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'utentiRepository': No qualifying
> bean of type 'Repository.UtentiRepository' available: expected at
> least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
> annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

```
package Entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class Utenti {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String cognome;
    private String email;
    private String pwd;

}
```

```
package Repository;
import Entity.Utenti;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UtentiRepository extends JpaRepository<Utenti, Long> {

}
```

```
package Service;

import DTO.UtentiDto;
import Entity.Utenti;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public interface UtentiService {

UtentiDto salvaUtente(UtentiDto utenteDto);
}
```

```
package ServiceImp;

import DTO.UtentiDto;
import Entity.Utenti;
import Repository.UtentiRepository;
import Service.UtentiService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Component
@Service
public class UtentiServiceImp implements UtentiService {

    @Autowired
    private UtentiRepository utentiRepository;
    @Autowired
    public UtentiServiceImp(UtentiRepository utentiRepository) {
        this.utentiRepository = utentiRepository;
    }
    @Override
    public UtentiDto salvaUtente(UtentiDto utentiDto){
        Utenti user=new Utenti();
        user.setId(utentiDto.getId());
        user.setNome(utentiDto.getNome());
        user.setCognome(utentiDto.getCognome());
        user.setEmail(utentiDto.getEmail());
        user.setPwd(utentiDto.getPwd());
        Utenti utenti=utentiRepository.save(user);
        UtentiDto utentiResponse=new UtentiDto();
        utentiResponse.setId(utenti.getId());
        utentiResponse.setNome(utenti.getNome());
        utentiResponse.setCognome(utenti.getCognome());
        utentiResponse.setEmail(utenti.getEmail());
        utentiResponse.setPwd(utenti.getPwd());
        return utentiResponse;

    }
}
```

```
package com.example.demo.RepositoryTest;
import Entity.Utenti;
import Repository.UtentiRepository;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.List;
@Component
@SpringBootTest
public class UtentiRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    UtentiRepository utentiRepository;

    @Test
    public void testSalvaUtente(){
    //Arrage
    Utenti utenti=Utenti.builder().nome("Mario").cognome("Scano").email("mario@mail.com").pwd("password").id(4L).build();
    Utenti utenti2=Utenti.builder().nome("Mario").cognome("Scano").email("mario@mail.com").pwd("password").id(3L).build();

    //Act
    utentiRepository.save(utenti);
    utentiRepository.save(utenti2);
    List<Utenti> lista=utentiRepository.findAll();
    //Assert
    Assertions.assertThat(lista).isNotNull();
    Assertions.assertThat(lista.size()).isEqualTo(2);
    }

}
```

Comment: You miss to enable the jpa repository scan:  `@EnableJpaRepositories` or if you wanr to  test with database, you should annotate your test class with `@DataJpaTest`

Comment: Remove `@Component` from your test class and also move everything into the `com.example.demo` package, and make sure your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in the `com.example.demo` package (everything else can be in sub packages).